# How can I match pair values in array for if condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make an array on basis of existing array following is my code which I have tried

```
var shortArray = new Array();
var resultArray = new Array();
shortArray = [
    ["Team 1", "Bye"],
    ["Team 2", "Bye"],
    ["Team 3", "Bye"],
    ["Team 4", "Team 5"]
]


for (var k = 0; k < shortArray.length; k++) {
    if (shortArray[k][0] == "Bye") {
        resultArray.push(0, 1);
    } else {
        resultArray.push(1, 0);
    }
}
```

I want an

```
resultArray=[["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","0"],["0","0"]]
```

like in single array whereever there is "Bye" name i need 0 value in resultArray

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please remove the tag Java, since Java and Javascript are not related.

Comment: The `resultArray` you're showing does not match with the requirement. If you want `0` in place of `Bye` and `1` elsewhere result should be `[["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","1"]]`, Note the last element

Answer (score 1):

Your listed output is an array containing arrays. To do that, you push an array, not individual values, into your array. E.g.:

```
resultArray.push(["0", "1"]);
// Note ---------^--------^
```

or

```
resultArray.push(["1", "0"]);
// Note ---------^--------^
```

as appropriate. Those each push an array with the entries, into `resultArray`, rather than pushing discrete entries into it.

Also note that you're checking the wrong value in `shortArray`. You should be checking index 1, not 0:

```
if (shortArray[k][1])
// ---------------^
```

Comment: TJ resultArray should be `[["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","0"],["0","0"]]`, this is not the only problem in the code in the question

Comment: You can also mention this: _If you want `0` in place of `Bye` and `1` elsewhere `resultArray` should be `[["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","1"]]`_ Note the last element. As the question is clear :)

Comment: how can we creat an empty new arrays like if i enter 5 it should creat an 5 new array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the similar form from shortArray, but change all value equal to `'Bye'` to `'1'` and others to `'0'`, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var shortArray= [["Team 1","Bye"],["Team 2","Bye"],["Team 3","Bye"],["Team 4","Team 5"]]

// Loop through shortArray, and generate a new array base on each item's value in shorArray.
var resultArray= shortArray.map(function(arr) {
  // Loop through arr to create a new array that, replace Bye to 0, other to 1.
  return arr.map(function(value) {
    return value === 'Bye' ? '0' : '1';
  });
  
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Console says "Access is denied.".

Comment: @RobG Not sure what's wrong, it shows what OP expects in my console.

Comment: @RobG Works for me, maybe some Security settings on your browser or network

Comment: Result array should be `[["1","0"],["1","0"],["1","0"],["0","0"]]` as per OP, you're snippet returns `[["0","1"],["0","1"],["0","1"],["0","0"]]`

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, changed my answer to fix that.

Comment: need an another help for this
[RoundNumber":1,
,RoundNumber":1,
,RoundNumber":1,
,RoundNumber":1,
,RoundNumber":2,
,RoundNumber":2,
,RoundNumber":3]
in this array the RoundNumber can be dynamic how can i check conditon that Roundnumber1 i have to add this team like there can be 5->Rounnumber1 and so on

Comment: @RohilPatel You should explain this question clearly the question is not clear, read my comments on the question and respond. If you have another query which is not related to this question in any way, ask another question

Comment: Tushar, updated my answer again, sorry was misleaded by OP's expect example. And @Rohil Patel, it seems to be another question, you should ask a new one.